# Why is the functions execute in finally in node js

Tags: node.js, function, bcrypt

In here my req.body.newTransactionPassword="1234";
i want encrypt that value but case is function is execute finally.I want get it into my order.Is that possible ..?

```html
console.log("1");
    var nwtp=req.body.newTransactionPassword;
    var setPassword = function(nwtp,cb){
      console.log("2");
        bcrypt.genSalt( 10, function(err, salt) {
          bcrypt.hash(nwtp, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return cb(err);
            } else {
              nwtp = hash;
              console.log(nwtp);
              return nwtp;

            }
          });
        });
    }
    setPassword(nwtp);
    console.log(nwtp);
    console.log("3");
```

out put is

```html
1
2
1234
3
$2a$10$kVmybMj7SsD5ip11lCU3AOFd4ZdKL6/0DzKADYcplIDx9qdZJAy/a
```

can i get it into that order..?

```
1
2
$2a$10$kVmybMj7SsD5ip11lCU3AOFd4ZdKL6/0DzKADYcplIDx9qdZJAy/a
3
$2a$10$kVmybMj7SsD5ip11lCU3AOFd4ZdKL6/0DzKADYcplIDx9qdZJAy/a
```

Comment: look this: https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use async library https://github.com/caolan/async

Then, your code might look like this

```
var saltResult = null;
var hashResult = null;
async.series([

  function(next) {
    bcrypt.genSalt( 10, function(err, salt) {
      saltResult = salt;
      next(err);
    });
  },

  function(next) {
    bcrypt.hash(nwtp, saltResult, function(err, hash) {
        hashResult = hash;
        next(err);
    });
  }],

  function(err) {
    // your final processing here
  }
);
```